# Django admin return query results to my change_list template

Tags: django, orm, django-admin

In my django project i would to display results of my ORM query in my personalized change_list.html template.
I do this:
in admin.py:

```
class temp_libraryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_filter = ('main_id__descr', 'l_type')


    def change_list(self, request, extra_context=None):

        #Here  we'll write ORM query, now test dict
        extra_context = {
            'cc': '123',
        }

        return super(temp_libraryAdmin, self).change_list(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

well, now in my footer block on change_list page:

```
{% block footer %}
<div id="footer-main">
    <p>FOOTERR</p>
    {% for lf in extra_context %}{{ lf.cc }}{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

but nothing is shown on my page.

How can i display data from a query in my admin page?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you redefined template in your class? `change_list_template = 'template.html'`

Comment: my change_list template is already change_list.html in my template/admin/app/model path

Answer (score 0):

I believe your are trying to override **changelist_view** function of modeladmin.
Now on checking the source code of it, the extra context is merged with the context dictionary as :

```
context.update(extra_context or {})
```

This context is then passed to the template. Hence in your case you can directly check if the variable is present, for eg :

```
extra_context = {
        'some_variable': '123',
    }
```

Then  in template check as:

```
{% if some_variable %}
```

Hope it helps.